# Program that has "select by marking areas as keep or remove"

Tags: selections

PowerPoint has an amazing "remove background" tool where the program guesses the user's selection while the user marks areas they do or don't want. Its a **time** and **number of clicks** efficient way to select complex things. Is there any graphic design program with a similar selection scheme? (user marking areas as "in" or "out" while the program fills in the blanks). I use GIMP but to my knowledge there is none...

I am aware of the "fuzzy select"/"magic wand" tool. It is not exactly what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer masking is usually the preferred method for extracting objects from backgrounds in raster image editing software. This is because it's non-destructive, which means you can easily fix mistakes. The original image is not actually edited, only its mask.

Photoshop has automated (AI assisted) select subject. Then you can just add a layer mask. It also has a feature called Select and Mask, which can be used to refine masks semi-automatically. There's also a Quick Selection tool, which can be used in combination with the Select and Mask functionality for mask refinement.

GIMP has a Foreground Select tool, which is semi-automated. You need to roughly select around the object with the Lasso tool, and then roughly paint inside the subject to mark it, then it creates a selection, which you can use to add a layer mask. Masks can also be edited in GIMP.

With raster image editors, there are also other methods to extract objects from backgrounds, such as manually drawing paths to then make a mask, or using colour channels as the basis for creating a mask. Which method to choose really depends on the image. Not all methods are good for all images.  It's always easier to extract subjects from a plain background compared to a complex background, even if you use AI assisted methods. Fully semi/fully-automated methods often fail for really complex images, and will generally need some manual fixing. Again, this is easily done if you use layer masking, since it's non-destructive.

Note: I answered [a question here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/159154/89608) which shows how to use GIMP's Foreground Select tool in more detail, and also how to refine a mask, if you are interested.